# Local scope object

Tags: javascript

I am just curious if there is such a thing as a 'local scope object' in JavaScript. If you invoke a function, it has a context (`this`), which is the object it has been called on (`function f() {return this;}; obj.f = f; obj.f(); //returns obj;`), and a scope, which is created on every function call. The scope is used to define local variables as in the following example:

```
var globalScopeVar = 1;
(function() {
    var localScopeVar = 2;
})();
```

In both scopes `this` refers to the global context (typically, `window`), since the function has not been called on any object. What I am interested in, though, is the 'scope object', i.e, the object where variables within a scope are defined on. For the global scope this is typically `window`, just like the global context:

```
window.globalScopeVar; // 1
```

However, what is the 'scope object' in the local scope of a function call? Does it even exist or is it accessible? Is there any way to access an object where `localScopeVar` is defined on?

```
(function() {
    var localScopeVar = 2;
    localScope.localScopeVar; // 2
})();
```

What is `localScope` in this example?

Comment: *"Does it even exist or is it accessible?"* Yes, it exists, but no, you can't access it.

Comment: I think "localScope" is the scope of the immediate closure, defined in the first line. Since this closure is essentially an anonymous function, that is executed immediatly (line: 4), you can not reference it.

Comment: Notice, that objects don't create scopes, only functions do. The scope is literally written to the script file, and you can't change it programmatically. Also, a function is not aware of the object it's defined in, unless you won't create a variable holding this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `localScope` is a [**Lexical Environment**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2).

As an answer to your question if `is it accessible`, ECMAScript Language Specification says the following:

> It is impossible for an ECMAScript program to directly access or
>   manipulate such values.